# Django-admin start project <name> creates old version django project

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I created a directory "DjangoProject1" and in it created django project through the terminal with the line

> $ django-admin startproject project

As I was expected, there were created two things in the directory "project": file "manage.py" and another directory "project".
The problem is that in that directory "project" there were: {**init**, setting, urls, wsgi}.py, but there wasn't file "asgi.py". From there I understood that there was created an old version django project. Again!
I checked it one more time in "urls.py" file and I saw this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

instead of this:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So it is definitely an old version of django project. I don't know why this problem occurs, as I installed a new version of django, and I was able to create new version django project, though I don't remember how I was doing that.
**Can anyone help me to liquidate this problem so that only new version django projects would be created?**
(PS before new version maybe I installed an old version, and probably in my computer now there are both: new and old versions of Django)

Comment: Did you check the version of Django active on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use **pip** instead of **pip3**

First Uninstall django installed by pip:

```
$ pip uninstall django
```

Next Install pip3:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

After that, Install Django using pip3:

```
$ pip3 install django
```

You can determine Django version that you want to install by this command:

```
$ pip3 install django==<version>
```

Comment: Thank youu, it worked! I really needed just delete django and reinstall with pip3 ^-^